# HTTPoison upload file

Tags: elixir

is there any tutorial how to upload local files with HTTPoison.post ? 
opening a file

```
{:ok, file} = File.open "README.md"
HTTPoison.post("#{url}", file, headers)
```

this is for dropbox integration using upload functionality

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer " \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"/Homework/math/Matrices.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary @local_file.txt
```

the problem is how to send —data-binary file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the equivalent of `curl`'s `--data-binary` would be to use `{:file, path}` as the body, as documented in [Hackney's README.md](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#send-a-body).

This should send the same request as your `curl` example:

```
HTTPoison.post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload",
               {:file, "local_file.txt"},
               [{"Authorization", "Bearer "}, ...])
```

Comment: opening a file {:ok, file} = File.open "README.md", [:write] then pass {:file, file} returns ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :hackney_bstr.to_binary/1

Comment: You have to pass the path as a String, not an opened file, like `{:file, "README.md"}`.

Answer (score 5):

Some sites require multi-part form data.  Try this if the above example does not work for your target.

```
HTTPoison.post!(
  url,
  {:multipart, [{:file, file}]},
  [],
  recv_timeout: 30000
 )
```

Comment: The `recv_timeout` and `timeout` options are pretty important if your files are large. You might be waiting a decent amount of time to hear back from the server.

Comment: This is what worked for me with `file` as the filepath, thanks!