# HTTPoison timeout error while upload big file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to upload file by multipart form with my API. This works fine locally.

However when I deploy into the server it thrown and error calling the HTTPoison request for file size >30MB. I don’t have any issue if the file size is smaller.

Not sure what is going on.

**Code**:

```elixir
{:ok, response} = HTTPoison.post(base_url(), body, header(), []) # <—- error on this line

case response.status_code do
200 ->
 data =
   response.body
   |> Jason.decode!()
   |> Map.get("outputs")
   |> List.first()

  {:ok, data}

  _ ->
  {:error, response.status_code}
end
```

**Error**:

```elixir
{:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: :timeout, id: nil}}
```

Do I need to add recv_timeout to the option? If so can I add in `runtime.exs` file so easier for me to change in case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37855971/532647 take a look at this question/answer. Also consider writing that `POST` as a curl command, to see if the timeout is enforced by your server or the client itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HTTPoison.Request.to_curl/1` to generate a `curl` command that can help you to debug.  I would try setting a high value for the `:recv_timeout` option, e.g.

```
HTTPoison.post(base_url(), body, header(), recv_timeout: :timer.seconds(30))
```

Comment: Increasing the `recv_timeout` to `150_000` helps

Comment: Great!  If the answer works, please mark the question as answered.